# not enough arguments for format string python mysql

Tags: python

I have a trouble with my program. I want input database from file txt. This is my source code

```
import MySQLdb
import csv
db=MySQLdb.connect(user='root',passwd='toor',
                        host='127.0.0.1',db='data')
cursor=db.cursor()
csv_data=csv.reader(file('test.txt'))
for row in csv_data:
        sql = "insert into `name` (`id`,`Name`,`PoB`,`DoB`) values(%s,%s,%s,%s);"
        cursor.execute(sql,row)
db.commit()
cursor.close()
```

After run that program, here the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "zzz.py", line 9, in <module>
    cursor.execute(sql,row)
  File "/home/tux/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 187, in execute
    query = query % tuple([db.literal(item) for item in args])
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

and this is my test.txt

```
4
zzzz
sby
2017-10-10
```

Please help, and thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, what does your `row` look like? It doesn't have enough elements

Comment: Can you please show a sample of how `test.txt` file look like?

Comment: welp, I solved it . thanks bro, u remind me about my test.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that you have posted the CSV file, the error should now be obvious to you - each line contains only one field, not the four that the SQL statement requires.

If that is the real format of your data file, it is not CSV data. Instead you need to read each group of four lines as one record, something like this might work:

```
LINES_PER_RECORD = 4
SQL = 'insert into `name` (`id`,`Name`,`PoB`,`DoB`) values (%s,%s,%s,%s)'

with open('test.txt') as f:
    while True:
        try:
            record = [next(f).strip() for i in range(LINES_PER_RECORD)]
            cursor.execute(SQL, record)
        except StopIteration:
            # insufficient lines available for record, treat as end of file
            break

    db.commit()
```

Comment: what the codes if I will change for each line contains four fields ?

Comment: If all four fields are on the same line, and are delimited consistently, then just use a `csv.reader()` as per your question. If that's not working update your question with sample data.